# Is dynamic report possible in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services

During runtime i want to design the report, like user has to simply drag and drop the columns what they want in the report.

Is this possible in SSRS?

If it is possible then experts please post some sample code or link. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services Version 11.0.2100.60

Comment: No... then they would be actually building the report them selves, and you are not needed :)

Comment: Suggest PivotTables / PowerBI in Excel instead

Comment: The closest you could probably do is to make the grouping values dependent on a parameter.  You can use a switch function to choose which field is used for a given row/column group.  But that would be clunky, and certainly not at the level of runtime customization you're talking about.